# Extract own class properties / members types

Tags: typescript

Having the following classes

```
class Model {
  status: string;
  save(): Promise<void>
}
```

```
class Car extends Model {
  brand!: string;
  dataValues!: { [key in keyof this]: Exclude<this[key], Function | undefined> };
}
```

```
car.dataValues.status // exists;
```

How can I type `dataValues!` to get only `keysof` the `Car` class? (ownPropertyNames)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you mean it should just have `brand`? `key in Exclude<keyof this, keyof Model>`

Comment: You can make it `Record<Exclude<keyof Car, keyof Model>, any> I guess, but what is the actual use case?  What are you doing with `Function | undefined`?  Can you explain it with words?

Comment: @Gerrit0 yes, thats the point. I was looking for a more flexible solution, but if it does not exists, yours is simple and valid.

Comment: @jcalz What I'm trying to achieve is to get members that aren't functions. This case is inspired on Sequelize developers, where in the instance, at runtime, sequelize will add more members coming from associations, but they were static typed in the Car class.

Comment: What type is `dataValues` supposed to be?  A string?  An array of strings?  An object with the same keys as the strings you're looking for?

Comment: Does [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAECyD2ATApiaBvAUNH0IBcx8BXCALj3wCcBLAOwHNoBeaAIjYG5tdIBPOsDxgAbsgAUASgoAFKvAC2NCMgA8I+DUQA+DNAC+mQ9EyhIMAPoBhMFWjIAHvmR1EMBCjRZc0AEZUwVwoCWkYWdjYeHHh8AAtkKgA1MBBiZAo6YgVfBPCARm4fCEVkADFiQXwaeDopPUNDTHw+AAdkaABpZD4IADkY2CJgWPoGVQAVABpoRN1WdGgAbQ7oemgAa274ADNocYBdCnHl-fsnFzcZ6AB+aDpkMTsKFf1Fzb4dvf3uU3AoaBsdkczlclkBGCi0EQRDAyVSyHI0AAglQAnxVABRBygYgoVRdHr9fCDfDDUaqay2ablSrVOjaabvT4eVDaOZLfZGTCmGoEaDAWzhe4AdwBtik3AFVAAdNDCHC0jBWIs2MUFGUKsAqjU2NNVYQSBBdewIKJkGxvtAAPRW+yo+BUUy2WUwhUI8Iq-yBRDGtgxeJJFJpC2ca22+DrMB8bncoA) work for you?

Comment: @jcalz Check this out https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js~Model.html

I don't see your solution scalable, having a lot of models. I think TS should have something more practical.

Comment: I don't understand what specifically is not scalable without some sort of example code that demonstrates the issue. All my suggestion does is extract the members of the subclass that are neither functions nor members of the superclass, but you need to add an intervening class or move that code out of the class in question to avoid illegal circular references. The compiler isn't happy defining a class property that depends on the types of properties of the same class that you're defining; it's circular. Maybe you can use a decorator instead? But without a multi-model example I'm not sure.